# CreateMutex -- "Access is denied"

Tags: c++, winapi

The following code works without any problem sometimes and at other times it throws "Access is denied" error. The behavior is not consistent.

```
_hMutex = CreateMutex(NULL, FALSE, MutexName);
    if (_hMutex == NULL) 
{
  throw MY_ERROR(GetLastError(), L"Error creating mutex handle");
}
```

I run my standalone executable which has this code, do the operation and exit. It is not a multithreaded application. I logon with the same user credential every time I run this.

Could you help me resolve this?

Thanks,
Hem

Comment: *"It is not a multithreaded application"*, Why do you need an Mutex if that be the case?

Comment: Why did you tag your question `multithreading` if it's not multithreaded?

Comment: @Als: Based on the fact that OP is trying to create a named mutex, I'd say that there are multiple processes trying to share a resource that is protected by a mutex. The fact that the OP's executable is not multithreaded is probably irrelevant here.

Comment: @Gabe: We could actually *guess* anything what we chose to, but that really wouldn't serve the cause of solving the problem conclusively.If one needs accurate answers and not mere *guesses* then they need to provide accurate details not vague worded questions.

Comment: Could it be that when CreateMutex succeeds, the mutex doesn't exist? When it fails, the mutex already exists and your app has limited access rights?

Comment: @Als: Creating a mutex is a common trick for checking whether your program is running already.

Comment: An application from another user may have already created a mutex with the same name you provide. Did you check for that case? Using WinObj or ProcessExplorer may help.

Comment: @Als: You're right that the question could be improved, but you can't expect every fact to be spelled out for you. Since there's rarely a reason to create a named mutex if you aren't coordinating multiple processes, the fact that there are multiple processes at play is implied by the use of a named mutex.

Comment: Is the code throwing MY_ERROR(ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED, L"Error creating mutex handle") or is it throwing a generic access denied exception?  (The latter could happen if MutexName is not a valid pointer.)

Comment: Come to think of it, several possible causes could be eliminated if you changed the code (for testing purposes) to replace MutexName with a string constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it finally. There is a service that runs with system account that creates the mutex and an exe run by user trying to access it. It was due to the permission.

Comment: It's a common mistake for UNIX programmers to assume a linear hierarchy of rights, with root/Administrator/SYSTEM on top. On Windows, neither `Administrator` nor `SYSTEM` have all rights, and they're definitely distinct accounts.

Answer (score 3):

If the mutex is a named mutex, and the object existed before this function call, the return value is a handle to the existing object, **GetLastError** returns `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS`, bInitialOwner is ignored, and the calling thread is not granted ownership.

However, if the caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` and the caller should use the **OpenMutex** function.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I read that in the MSDN site but what causes this, limited access rights? The user has admin privileges.

Comment: Can someone throw some light on the "limited access rights", please? I'm using a domain account which part of the administrators group of the machine. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Today I had a similar issue, but with different sessions.
The mutex is named and has the prefix `Global\`.
When one application created the named global mutex no other application of different user accounts was allowed to synchronize with the same mutex.
CreateMutex always returned the error `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`. OpenMutex succeeded, but the mutex couldn't be used for synchronization.

The solution is that each application must access the global mutex with `CreateMutexEx` (with only `SYNCHRONIZE` requested) AND you must specify the SecurityAttributes. The default SecurityAttributes disallows sharing between user accounts.

A working code looks like:

```
HANDLE hMutex;
{
    DWORD dwRes, dwDisposition;
    PSID pEveryoneSID = NULL;
    PACL pACL = NULL;
    PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR pSD = NULL;
    EXPLICIT_ACCESS ea[1];
    SID_IDENTIFIER_AUTHORITY SIDAuthWorld =
            SECURITY_WORLD_SID_AUTHORITY;
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa;
    LONG lRes;

    // Create a well-known SID for the Everyone group.
    if(!AllocateAndInitializeSid(&SIDAuthWorld, 1,
                     SECURITY_WORLD_RID,
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                     &pEveryoneSID))
    {
        _tprintf(_T("AllocateAndInitializeSid Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize an EXPLICIT_ACCESS structure for an ACE.
    // The ACE will allow Everyone read access to the key.
    ZeroMemory(&ea, 1 * sizeof(EXPLICIT_ACCESS));
    ea[0].grfAccessPermissions = SYNCHRONIZE;
    ea[0].grfAccessMode = SET_ACCESS;
    ea[0].grfInheritance= NO_INHERITANCE;
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeForm = TRUSTEE_IS_SID;
    ea[0].Trustee.TrusteeType = TRUSTEE_IS_WELL_KNOWN_GROUP;
    ea[0].Trustee.ptstrName  = (LPTSTR) pEveryoneSID;
    
    // Create a new ACL that contains the new ACEs.
    dwRes = SetEntriesInAcl(1, ea, NULL, &pACL);
    if (ERROR_SUCCESS != dwRes) 
    {
        _tprintf(_T("SetEntriesInAcl Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    // Initialize a security descriptor.  
    pSD = (PSECURITY_DESCRIPTOR) LocalAlloc(LPTR, 
                             SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_MIN_LENGTH); 
    if (NULL == pSD) 
    { 
        _tprintf(_T("LocalAlloc Error %u\n"), GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup; 
    } 
 
    if (!InitializeSecurityDescriptor(pSD,
            SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR_REVISION)) 
    {  
        _tprintf(_T("InitializeSecurityDescriptor Error %u\n"),
                                GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup; 
    } 
 
    // Add the ACL to the security descriptor. 
    if (!SetSecurityDescriptorDacl(pSD, 
            TRUE,     // bDaclPresent flag   
            pACL, 
            FALSE))   // not a default DACL 
    {  
        _tprintf(_T("SetSecurityDescriptorDacl Error %u\n"),
                GetLastError());
        goto Cleanup; 
    } 

    // Initialize a security attributes structure.
    sa.nLength = sizeof (SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = pSD;
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    hMutex = CreateMutexExW(&sa, L"Global\\MyNamedMutex", 0, SYNCHRONIZE);

Cleanup:

    if (pEveryoneSID) 
        FreeSid(pEveryoneSID);
    if (pAdminSID) 
        FreeSid(pAdminSID);
    if (pACL) 
        LocalFree(pACL);
    if (pSD) 
        LocalFree(pSD);
}

// Do something with hMutex
WaitForSingleObject(hMutex, INFINITE);

CloseHandle(hMutex);
```

Source links:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexexa
- https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/win32/secauthz/creating-a-security-descriptor-for-a-new-object-in-c--?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because a mutex with `MutexName` already exists. You're creating the mutex with default security descriptor, which (depending on how you're using this mutex) may not permit other uses of it.

For more, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx). A useful snippet:

> If the mutex is a named mutex and the object existed before this
>   function call, [elided], if the
>   caller has limited access rights, the function will fail with
>   `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED` and the caller should use the OpenMutex function.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what "limited access rights" means. Could you throw some light here? The application is run by Windows user who has admin privileges. How do I get out of this?

Comment: The security token determines how processes/services in different contexts can access the mutex. What are you trying to use this one for? And are you perhaps using a common name that another might have picked?

Comment: I'm confident that the name cannot be guessed, it is a combination of words. Moreover, no other applications are running. I'll check on the security token.

Comment: Do you close the handle to the Mutex via CloseHandle when it is not needed anymore?